# android ProGuard can File Name will change

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Can we change file name like "MainActivity.java" to "ab.java" in proGuard, if yes than pls send me that code because i don't know how to put rules in ProGuard Confing file.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: i tried to remove comment from project.property file (proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.tx) and put some ready made code in proguard-project.txt like (-keep public class * extends Activity) but i want change file name ,is it possible?

Comment: Edit your question and put this information there .. follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank u sir ,but you know the answer of my question or you can't understand what i  am saying? my english is weak so sry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activity class that are referenced from your AndroidManifest.xml can not be renamed (aka obfuscated) by ProGuard.

This is due to the aapt process which will automatically create rules like this:

```
# view AndroidManifest.xml #generated:14
-keep class com.example.HelloWorldActivity { <init>(...); }
```

If you need to obfuscate also such classes, you will need to use a commercial obfuscator like [DexGuard](http://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard).